# httpd and mod_wsgi ran with wrong python version

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi

I am deploying a Django project with httpd on `RHEL7`. And changed the system default python version to python 3.4. But after I restarted the httpd, it still used python 2.7.

I searched a lot and it is mostly because `mod_wsgi` was built under the wrong python version. However, I checked that `mod_wsgi` was installed under python 3.4.

May I know how to make it run under the correct python version? Not too sure if httpd has a default python version. Thanks very much for your help!

[Error Stack trace: No module named embed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/et0vX.png)

Comment: Are you using virtualenv?

Comment: Nope, I didn't use virtualenv since i will only use python3.4 for this server. I found that it was because I didn't load mod_wsgi module into httpd...since I don't have sudo access to the server, I cannot configure mod_wsgi directly to httpd I think...

Answer (score 0):

I just find that it was due to the fact that I didn't Load 'wsgi_module' to the httpd conf file. I just followed the instruction https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/mod_wsgi to add LoadModule into httpd.conf file. It solves my problem and now runs in the correct python version!

```
 LoadModule wsgi_module "/usr/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi-py34.cpython-34m.so"  
 WSGIPythonHome "/usr"
```

But I think it is strange that it will show `module wsgi_module is already loaded,skipping`. If I comment these lines, it will again run in python2.7

Comment: Btw,I found wsgi.conf in /etc/httpd/conf.modules.d    LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so. I think probably it needs to be pointed to the correct path.

Comment: You need to first disable the mod_wsgi which was installed using system packages.